# How can I create a multiline spolier?

Tags: support, spoilers

I was editing [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/229847/46688), trying to get the figures into spoiler tags (i.e. `>!`). But for some reason, we seem to be unable to to do multiple line spoiler blockquotes.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

My Syntax:

```
>! SOME TEXT
>! SOME TEXT
>! SOME TEXT
>! SOME TEXT
>! SOME TEXT
>! SOME TEXT
```

and I also tried

```
>! SOME TEXT
>
>! SOME TEXT
>
>! SOME TEXT
```

Comment: HTML tags are supported, so you should be able to add `<br/>` tags to your spoiler for multiline spoilers.

Comment: See also /q/6831